# How to concurrently test iPhone app and web browser backend?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, saucelabs

I need to automate the testing of an iPhone app.

Basically the iPhone app will do something (e.g. register, purchase an item) and then I need to check the web backend (PHP) to ensure I can see what the iPhone app did (e.g. I can see the new user and the item they purchased).

Is there a known strategy for this?

For example, I have two test suites: the first one runs the iPhone bit, and the second one runs the web backend bit? Is there a tutorial or best practice for this? I will probably use webdriver.io + saucelabs.

Thanks.

Comment: actually to test iphone app, i install xcode and appium ios on my mac and than write my testcases through eclipse.

Comment: Thanks. So it's just like running a normal test?